# MediaPlayer finalized without being released

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My application seems to work fine, but I get `MediaPlayer finalized without being released` warnings and I'm not sure why I'm getting them. The weird thing is that they only show up when I use `MediaPlayer.create(ctxt, resid)` to play resource files (.ogg) and not when I use `setDataSource(path)` to play files from the SD card.

I've looked at a lot of the other post on Stack Overflow, check out the developer docs, and tried different combinations of things (too many to list), but nothing seems to get rid of the error. Not sure if it's a bug or something I'm doing.

I'm using a ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter and basically, when you tap on the page it plays the sound. When you swipe to the next page it stops the sound from playing (if it's still playing). Here's the code for that part, but I've removed it during tests and it doesn't seem to make a difference, but I figured I'd include it just in case:

```java
public void stopAudioInFragment() {
    ViewPageFragment page = (ViewPageFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
    if (page != null) {
        page.stopAudio();
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant code for the fragment:

```java
public static MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private int mAudioId;
private boolean mIsAudioFile = false;

public void playAudio() {
    // Setup media player to play audio
    mIsAudioFile = false;

    stopAudio();
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    if (!mIsAudioFile && mAudioId != -1 && mPlayer != null) {
        // Play local resource audio
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, mAudioId);
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopAudio();
            }
        });

    } else if (mAudioId != -1 && mPlayer != null) {
        // Play audio file on SD card
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(audio_file_path);
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    stopAudio();
                }
            });

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    mPlayer.start();
}

public void stopAudio() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
        mPlayer.reset(); // Might not be necessary, since release() is called right after, but it doesn't seem to hurt/cause issues
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopAudio();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Again, the above works fine and doesn't seem to cause any problems. If I'm on a page and tap it several times, it starts to play the sound and then stops/plays with each new tap. It looks like the warnings show up when it destroys the page and then GC runs. There's one warning for each time I've played the audio file.

I'd like to know why I get `MediaPlayer finalized without being released` warnings only when it plays resource files and not when it plays files from the SD card. As far as I can tell, it should always be finalized before it's GC'd. Any ideas?

**Update:** I did a few more tests to try to see if I could pinpoint anything "weird" going on, but the only thing I can really see is that it only affects files in the res/raw folder. Here's what I can add:

- The files that are generating the warnings are in the res/raw folder.
- If I move the files (.ogg and also tested with .wav) to the assets folder and play them from there,
  the MediaPlayer DOES NOT generate any warnings.
- I replaced some of the files in res/raw with .mp3, .wav and .mp4
  audio files and they ALL GENERATED WARNINGS, just like the original
  .ogg files did.
- I successfully played .mp3, .wav and .mp4 files from the SD card and they DID NOT
  generate the MediaPlayer warnings.
- To clarify: all files play correctly without any problems from a
  users perspective. What I'm trying to figure out is why the
  MediaPlayer generates warnings for audio files in res/raw.

Looks like the problem has to do with how the MediaPlayer handles resources in the res/raw folder, but I have no idea what the "issue" is or why it generates the MediaPlayer warnings.

Comment: Is there a reason to call reset and then release, I'm pretty sure you just want to use release?

Comment: For differnt devices this will work differently as the media player is just a wrapper for the native OEMs and the native service is all device dependent. the same thing applies to camera as well. even if you fix your managed code to remove these warnings they might appear on another device

Comment: @RSenApps Thanks for the comment. I want to say I had some issues at one time if I just called release() and didn't call reset() before, but I don't remember. In any case, I don't think it hurts to call reset() before release(), since reset() sets the MediaPlayer to an uninitialized state and release() releases resources associated with the referenced MediaPlayer object. However, you're right, the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#releaseplayer) indicates that you really only need to release and then set to null.

Comment: @PulkitSethi, thanks. I have three devices (GS3 (4.1.2), Xoom (CM 4.2.2) and Nexus 7 2012 (4.3)) that I've tested on with the same code and they all produce the exact same result/warnings. I'm not sure there's really anything else I can do to "fix" my code so I guess I'm just going to have to live with the warnings and chalk this up to one that can be safely ignored.

Comment: I am also frustrated with it seems a similar problem. Also using fragments and ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I am only getting these warnings for one particular ogg sound effect at the moment, I have several. I have tried all combinations of releasing and reseting. I get the warning as the sound starts not when it completes. Using an on completionListener with release does not make any difference. Can I ignore the warning ?

Comment: @RyanHeitner, if you're not seeing any problems with your app, then you can probably safely ignore the warnings. I would fully test thought, just to make sure. I wonder if this has something to do with .ogg files, since my local resource files are .ogg and they generate the warnings. The files on my SD card are .3gp files and don't generate the warnings.

Comment: @Jason I am ignoring for now and will come back to this later. Hopefully someone will answer.

Answer (score 1):

Release media player when no use by `mp.release();`.
It will solve your problem.

For ex.

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {    
        mp.release();
    }
});
```